# Generate an array from unordered list in HTML using Java Script

Tags: javascript

With the help of xml and PHP, I create a list in html code

HTML code is like this

```
<ul id="msglst">
    <li> <div id="10"> … </div></li>
    <li><div id="25"> … </div></li>
    <li><div id="116"> … </div> </li>
    <li><div id="255">…</div></li>
    <li> <div id="319"> … </div></li>
    <li><div  id="625">…</div> </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get an array that store id of div tag under ul tag

In this picture , i described required array
visit http://prntscr.com/2l7sez

Comment: question edited and explained in image Thanx

Comment: Do you want an array to begin with 1, not 0 index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, IE8 and up. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9NM8/1/).

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#msglst > li > div'),
    idList = [];
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    idList.push(+elements[i].getAttribute('id'));
}

alert(JSON.stringify(idList));
```

Comment: question edited and explained in image Thanks

Comment: I updated the fiddle to include a cast to turn the id's into integers. Otherwise that's exactly what you get from this. The alert (And `json.stringify`) are just to demonstrate the result.

Comment: your code also work on that i need  Thanks

Comment: could you favor me again, document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML is not working properly please see this link http://prntscr.com/2ljvq0 Thanks

Comment: do you call it inside `divClick` ? If yes, do you might want to pass `"div1"` instead of `10` ?

Comment: actual code is : <li><div id="10" onclick="divChange(10);"> ... </div></li>

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
var ulEle = document.getElementById("msglst"),
    liEle = ulEle.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    arr = [];
for(var li = 0, len = liEle.length; li < len; li++) {
    var divEle = liEle[li].getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var d = 0, dlen = divEle.length; d < dlen; d++) {
        arr.push(divEle[d].getAttribute("id"));
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NwgD/)

Comment: hi sir ,question described in image Thanks

Comment: that is what you get in console.log(arr);

Comment: could you favor me again, document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML is not working properly please see this link http://prntscr.com/2ljvq0 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using jQuery you can do it like this:

```
var array = $('#msglst').find('div').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).toArray();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Paqk/)

**Edit**

It will also work if you replace `$('#msglst').find('div')` with `$('#msglst div')`

Comment: why am I being downvoted? Is this because my example requires jQuery? But I specified it in my answer

Comment: The first way to select the divs is the "better" one, as the selectors in the second one will be matched right to left. An alternative way to write the `.find` one would be `$('div', '#msglst')`. Passing the context like this can be read as "Match all divs inside `#msglst`", just like the method using `.find`. `$('#msglst div')` would read as "Match all divs with `#msgList` as a parent" and would match all divs, then sorting out all the ones which aren't inside `#msglst`. Practically, the difference in performance won't matter in most cases, though.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting I didn't know about it. Thank you for the information

Comment: You're welcome. :) It's just a somewhat long side note. *I also countered the downvoter.*

Comment: question edited and explained in image Thanks

Comment: could you favor me again, document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML is not working properly please see this link http://prntscr.com/2ljvq0 Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
arr=[];
$("msglst>li>div").each(function(ele){ 
   arr.push(ele.id)
})
```

Comment: The question doesn't have a jQuery Tag.

Comment: question edited and explained in image Thanks